# get dynamically added element value using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created a script while making an ajax call i have a div in which there is a table within that table tr there is a list of data I want to get that newly added tr value but when I try to do that it gives me an error of undefined as when I see that row is just added is it possible to get new added row value by class name within same call made ? Please refer my code below  I am not good in explaining my question but your comments are appreciated I can answer them.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    symbol: symbol,
    val1: val1,
    val2: val2,
    val3: val3,
    val4: val4,
    val5: val5,
    val6: val6,
    val7: val7,
    line_val: line_val
  },
  dataType: "text",
  url: "getCompanyData.php",
  success: function(data) {
    $('.content_panel').append(data);
    $('.load_analyzer').hide();
  }
});

if ($('.radiobox').hasClass('activeradio')) {
  var active_line = $('.activeradio .line_check').val();
  var new_added = $('.line2').attr('data-line2');
}
console.log('New Added Value : ' + new_added); // This is showing as undefined as this row is just being added with above call how do I get this value
```

Comment: Put the `if` statement *inside* the `success` callback. As your code stands you're attempting to access an element that doesn't yet exist in the DOM.

Comment: wow that's awesome please post an answer and also a bit explanation that why this does not happen i mean i placed after ajax call as of request was executed

Comment: I added an answer for you. The issue is due to asynchronous code. I'd suggest researching that if you're unsure about how exactly it works.

Comment: An AJAX call is like asking your friend to go to the shop and get some milk, but as soon as they leave you make a coffee and try to add milk.  You have to wait until your friend comes back with the milk before you can add it to your coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you need to place the `if` statement *inside* the `success` handler:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    symbol: symbol,
    val1: val1,
    val2: val2,
    val3: val3,
    val4: val4,
    val5: val5,
    val6: val6,
    val7: val7,
    line_val: line_val
  },
  dataType: "text",
  url: "getCompanyData.php",
  success: function(data) {
    $('.content_panel').append(data);
    $('.load_analyzer').hide();

    if ($('.radiobox').hasClass('activeradio')) {
      var active_line = $('.activeradio .line_check').val();
      var new_added = $('.line2').attr('data-line2');
    }
    console.log('New Added Value : ' + new_added)    
  }
});
```

This is because the AJAX request is asynchronous - this is what the first 'A' stands for. It means that logic execution continues on passed the request while it's in progress. It's only once a response is received then that the `success` handler is executed. This may be miliseconds later, or minutes later. Either way, in your original code you will have already tried to read the DOM before you've updated it. Hence the issue.

Comment: thank you sooo much for your help you solved my problem

Comment: No problem, glad to help.